# Python pandas, set background colors for dataframe cells by another dataframe

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grp':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'pos' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]})

>>> df
  grp  pos
0   A    1
1   A    1
2   B    1
3   B    1
4   B    2
```

I would like to set background color for the same values in each column.
For example, in column grp, first two values AA should have background color 1, and BBB background color 2. In pos column, 1111 should have color x, 2 color y.

I tried to construct a dataframe with colors:

```
df_colors = pd.DataFrame({'grp':['#1d77ab', '#1d77ab', '#1a7899', '#1a7899', '#1a7899'], 'pos' : ['#1d77ab', '#1d77ab', '#1d77ab', '#1d77ab', '#167a7e']})

>>> df_colors
       grp      pos
0  #1d77ab  #1d77ab
1  #1d77ab  #1d77ab
2  #1a7899  #1d77ab
3  #1a7899  #1d77ab
4  #1a7899  #167a7e
```

If I have colors in dataframe how to apply style to dataframe df with colors in dataframe df_colors?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with add `background-color`, only necessary same index and columns names of both `DataFrame`s:

```
(df.style.apply(lambda x: 'background-color: ' + df_colors, axis=None)
   .to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False))
```